# How to replace name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/services/Servlet"), value = "/SomethingElse/services/Servlet"),

Tags: content-management-system, aem

In AEM 6 SP3, I have a servlet where I want to replace the property name value from "/bin/services/Servlet" something else like:

, value = "/SomethingElse/services/Servlet"

How do I enable the same and checkin to my git/SVN ?

Comment: Note that as per https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html mounting servlets on paths is not recommended if you can avoid it. Quoting that page, "creating a resource at the desired path, with a resource type that maps to a servlet, provides the same result in most cases while taking advantage of more Sling built-in features" - including fine-grained access control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AEM allow few context path to be accessed as servlet, `/bin` is one of default path which is used for internal servlets, and for any project specific servlet you might need to use some different content path for that you need to add your context path in OSGI service `Apache Sling Servlet Resolver` PID: `org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.SlingServletResolver`

Comment: Thanks Mohit, but I guess that can't be added in the code repo to checkin. Can we add this context path as a runmode somehow ?

Comment: Yes, create an runmode with <pid>.xml in your runmode folder and add all existing configuration + your new servlet context path.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, but it seems this pid is not listed in the /system/console/configMgr to add it in the runmodes and get the parameter details to append.

Comment: @Ajax: Search for service name `Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler`

Comment: Hi @Ajax did it work for you, for me it only works if i keep everything emtpy in execution path, if i add /SomethingElse/services/Servlet it starts giving 403 after a 302 redirect

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add an URL Mapping in `Apache Sling Resource Resolver Factory`.

Sample config file that can be deployed as part of the application:

`org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    resource.resolver.mapping="[/bin/services/:/SomethingElse/services/]"/>
```